# Nugeting a multiplatform project on Windows

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nuget, nuget-package

I am currently developing an app on Xamarin Forms that is targeted to be deployed on iOS and Android. One of the features of the app is a custom view of the camera. The camera module in itself was developed independently for iOS and Android, because frame by frame analysis is required. Then, a Custom Renderer (ExportRenderer) was created to consume the camerapreview component from Xamarin.Forms.

As this camera module will be used in many apps and it has lots of dependencies, I was considering nugeting the module, and for that I found lots of tutorials, for instance: https://lachlanwgordon.com/nugeting-a-custom-visual/.

The problem is that when I try to create a Multiplatform Library project on Visual Studio 2019 (on Windows), the option is not available which lead me to think that I requiere a Mac for such a project.

Is it possible to create a Multiplatform Library project on Windows? If so, which dependencies are needed?

I thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-packages-for-xamarin#write-your-platform-specific-code) might be a useful guide to create Nuget Packages.

You can install [Cross-Platform .NET Standard Plugin Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-473885.PluginForXamarinTemplates) to easily create a new project that is ready to become a Nuget package.